# iOS Voiceover not reading dynamically loaded content

Tags: javascript, ios, polymer, accessibility, voiceover

iOS safari voiceover will skip reading some of the visible content in web applications built on Polymer 1.

The content is visible and reads some times, but when navigating through the page again, it just stops in the middle and repeats the same content when trying to swipe next item.

I tried with `aria-live`, and it didn't work for me (applied at different levels of the app).

Comment: Hello @aditang, welcome to StackOverflow :-) While you describe your problem quite good, there is no way for us to determine the cause of that problem. This is because your question lacks the HTML code that is produced by your app and then red by the Safari voiceover. Try to create a __minimal example__ of your page that creates the error and add it to your question by editing it, so we are able to help. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/20801208)

Comment: Yes, a code sample will help. Also expand on the gestures you're using and what you were doing before the problem happened and what you did just prior to the problem. It sounds like you can swipe right to go to the next DOM element (or more accurately, the next element in the accessibility tree), but that eventually swipe right does not work?  Does swiping right work correctly at some point and then suddenly stops? If so, what happened before it stopped working? Your title says dynamic content. Are you using `aria-live` on any components? Elements can be skipped if `aria-hidden` is set.

Comment: @slugolicious Sure, I will add some code. coming to the gestures, Yes I am doing swipe right to go next DOM element and it works for some time and then it stop like the DOM ended. Swipe right will not go further but swipe left will go back. it's intermittent randomly will stop at some element. And there are no hidden content. But Polymer will remove content from DOM and will add as we navigate through the app like other single page applciations. `aria-live = "politte"` is  added at wrapper level of the component.

Comment: E.g., there is a list of 5 items and the other app. When I navigate first time to the page, the voice over will read all the list-items. then navigate to the other page and some back it will stop at 2 or 3rd list element and swipe right will not go further. Refresh the page will solve again can Navigate to all the list items.

Comment: Please `edit` your question to add all relevant data, including code. Comments are regularly deleted and are only for ephemeral comments and questions, nothing important

Comment: when swiping right doesn't work and you know there are more elements, try setting your rotor to "vertical navigation" or "buttons" or some element that you know is further down in the DOM and see if swipe **down** lets you get to it